# How to make events in an iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to make a chrome extension app that, if I press `tab` key, it make 4 spaces.

But the problem is the website looks like this.

[image]

So, the body contains `iframe`. And, I tried many things on stackoverflow. But only one thing seemed work. But I got this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
```

So, I searched but, I just found the questions or the answers which talk about, when you own a website and you can implement the `child-frame` and the `parent-frame`.

However, In my case, I don't own the website. I just would like to make key events and click events in the `child-frame` from `parent-frame` and add text to the `child-frame`

The website doesn't use the `parent-frame` but `child-frame`'s width and height are 100%. So, It's like I use `iframe` instead of the `original frame`.

And I'd like to implement when I type in textarea or code, the `tab` key event works.

Comment: AFAICT all you need is to declare your content script with `"all_frames": true` in manifest.json, see the documentation. When it runs inside an iframe you can access the iframe's `document` directly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is doable.
Site within an iframe is going to be a different domain owned by some third-party and due to technical and security considerations for cross-frame communications, you will have no control over it.